# Hibernate @ManyToOne mapping: object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, many-to-one

I have two classes like these:

```
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "DBId")
    private Long DBId = null;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.FALSE)
    private SampleSet samples;
}

public class SampleSet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "DBId")
    private Long DBId = null;

    private String uniqueId;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "SampleSet_samplesSet")
    private Set<String> samplesSet = new TreeSet<>();
}
```

and I have a code like this:

```
public void modifyAndSaveParent(Parent p, Session session) {
    SampleSet s = (SampleSet) session.getNamedQuery("SampleSet.loadByUniqueId").setParameter("uniqueId", p.getSampleSet().getUniqueId()).uniqueResult();
    if (s == null)
        throw new RuntimeException();
    else
        p.setSampleSet(s);

    session.save(p);
    session.flush();
}
```

The problem is that an exception is thrown on session.flush():

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: SampleSet
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:509)
        at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:309)
        at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:319)
        at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.findDirty(TypeHelper.java:294)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.findDirty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4051)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.dirtyCheck(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:535)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.isUpdateNecessary(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:235)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:164)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:228)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1240)
```

But as you can see the SampleSet must be already persisted. What should I do?

In fact, I don't want to use cascades. I want to manage SampleSets manually and don't want the changes to Parent to be cascaded.

Comment: check for cascade option in `@ManyToOne`

Comment: I don't want a cascade. I want to manage the SampleSets manually. I don't want the changes to be cascaded.

Comment: so save s manually...

Comment: It is definitely saved, when I retrieved it by a query

Comment: probably the object gets saved but does not get refreshed in the the related object. So the object is not in the managed state. Maybe refresh operation will help. Any reason why cascade is being ruled out?

Comment: First, what do you mean object gets saved but does not get refreshed? Second, because I don't want the changes, deletes, inserts, etc. to be cascaded

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your SampleSet first then save parent object.

Add `session.save(s);` before `session.save(p);`

Comment: First, it must be already persisted, without needing to save it again. Second, the session already contains it. session.contains(s) returns true. Third, I did a session.update(s) with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first sync the Parent and then save it. Something like that:

```
p = (Parent) session.load(Parent.class, p.getId());
p.setSampleSet(s);
session.save(p);
session.flush();
```

Comment: Parent is not persisted before

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the code snippet above. Solved it. tried to delete the question but not succeeded.
In fact I had a List parents in the Parent class. and the SampleSets inside them were not persisted.